# Size of HashMap when using same literal/string Object as Key?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

Please let me know if my understanding is correct:
Size of HashMap is 2 here because String equals(compare the state/content and not the location on heap) method comes into picture when we put the keys in the below map

```
Map hashMap = new HashMap();

hashMap.put("one", "1");
hashMap.put(new String("one"), "2");
hashMap.put("two", "3");
System.out.println("Hash Map KeySet Size : " + hashMap.keySet().size());
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

[source code is the proof.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29)

Since you are using Strings  as keys , `key.equals(k)`  is `true`  for the case `"one"` as key.

```
     public V put(K key, V value) {
387         if (key == null)
388             return putForNullKey(value);
389         int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
390         int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
391         for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
392             Object k;
393             if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
394                 V oldValue = e.value;
395                 e.value = value;
396                 e.recordAccess(this);
397                 return oldValue;
398             }
399         }
400 
401         modCount++;
402         addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
403         return null;
404     }
```

Here is the essential condition check:

```
if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct.

For reference you can simply run `hashMap.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. and You can't have duplicate keys in `Map`.Both `"one"` and `new String("one")` has same state(`"one".equals(new String("one"))`).So in this case first two has same key.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Map` uses the `equals()` method to check the existence of a key in the `Map`. It checks if the Objects-keys are meaningfully equal. In String class the `equals()` method is overrided by the `API` and the comparison `"one"` to `new String("one")` returns true. After `equals()` method returning true, the new element replaces the old, since duplicate keys are not allowed in `Map`. Therefore you have only one element with key "one"